# Jasmine working with Q in async & promise style?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, jasmine, bdd

I wrote a very simple async promise chain below:

```
"use strict";
var Q = require("q");

describe('foobar', function() {
    it('should do async add', function() {
        return Q.fcall(function () {
            return "a";
        })
        .then(function (obj) {
            return obj + "a";
        })
        .then(function (obj) {
            return obj + "a";
        })
        .then(function (obj) {
            expect(obj).toEqual("aaa");
        })
    });
});
```

But when I run "jasmine-node mytest_spec", i got:

> Finished in 0.004 seconds 1 test, 1 assertion, 0 failures, 0 skipped

What mistake I made please? How should I fix this?

Comment: Did you bother search a minimum before asking ? jasmine describes a specific api to work with async operations, please just check the doc, ctrl+F "async" ,how hard can it be ?

Comment: Sorry but please don't blame me, I read both Jasmine 1.3 and 2.0 doc, I just missed one point... Jasmine-node and protractor both use Jasmine 1.3, I was thinking it should be 2.0...

Answer (score 0):

I read both Jasmine 1.3 and 2.0 doc, I just missed one point... Jasmine-node and protractor both use Jasmine 1.3, I was thinking it should be 2.0...

So the correct working code should be:

```
runs(function () {
    flag = false;
    return Q.fcall(function () {
        console.log("first");
        return "a";
    })
    .then(function (obj) {
        console.log("second");
        return obj + "a";
    })
    .then(function (obj) {
        console.log("third");
        return obj + "a";
    })
    .then(function (obj) {
        value = obj;
        flag = true;
    });
});

waitsFor(function() {
    return flag;
}, "The Value should be incremented", 50);

runs(function() {
    expect(value).toEqual("aaa");
});
```